# How to force ember data to reset all fields of a record on reload?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember with ember data and i have a scenario where I need to reload a model. On reload, when the data is fetched and some fields of that model are null, the older data still persists. For eg., if I have a Post model

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

Now the first time the server returns the following data:

```
{
  "post" : {
              "id" : "1",
              "name" : "new post",
              "description": "some description"
           }
}
```

After reload is called, the server returns the following data:

```
{
  "post" : {
              "id" : "1",
              "name" : "new post",
           }
}
```

So after the reload, "description" field should be set to null for that record. But the old data ie., "some description" still persists in that field.

How can I force ember data to reset all fields on reload?

Comment: Why is the description field missing in the second call to the server ? Shouldn't description be "description": "" ?

Comment: Server sends data for a field only if it is present. In this case, the description has become null and hence the server doesnt send it.

Comment: Don't you have any way to force the server to send an empty value if description is null ? I'm pretty sure it would solve your problem.

Comment: It might solve the problem. But I am trying to solve it from the client side. If the server sends values for every field even if it is empty, that would increase the amount of data sent from the server for each response. For eg, if there are 10 fields in a model but only 5 are applicable to a particular record, server will still send all 10 fields. This will be worse if we're fetching a big list of records.

Comment: That's very true. Well I guess your only option will be to manually empty all fields on your model before reloading it from the server since reload only override fields explicitly sent by the server. rollback() won't help you since your record was not empty to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the exact feature you want [was deprecated a few months ago](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/12/25/ember-data-1-0-beta-14-released.html#toc_breaking-changes). At the bottom it mentions a way in the serializer to replace missing properties with `null`.

```
// app/serializers/application.js
// or App.ApplicationSerializer
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  normalize: function(type, hash, prop) {
    hash = this._super(type, hash, prop);

    // Find missing attributes and replace them with `null`
    type.eachAttribute(function(key) {
      if (!hash.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        hash[key] = null;
      }
    });

    return hash;
  }
});
```